# How to show a text only while printing and not while preview in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Iam trying to print a footer text only when user is printing the report and not to be shown while previewing.

I have tried using the WhilePrintingRecords; in the text object's formula editor but has not been able to get it to work.

WhilePrintingRecords; 1=1

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701357/crystal-report-suppress-hightligthed-fields-on-print

Comment: Thank you for the response @AleksandarZoric.   Thanks for the link.  But,  while in the preview if user clicks the print icon how to know?? so that at that point we can apply some logic.

Comment: I have not tested this but according to the link (So for example in preview mode the parameter will be set to True and False in print mode) - he has a boolean parameter which will be set to True if in preview mode and False in print mode.  So programatically you can use that boolean and check its status when required and then apply your logic.